# How to host sub domain on a different server?

Tags: domains, subdomain, nameserver, cloudflare

Web hosting scenario of landing page (foobar.com) built in Jekyll and hosted on Cloudcanyon. Need a sub domain (chat.foobar.com) for a chatroom to go to a different server like Heroku to run the chatroom. My research shows this could be done with a cname but I'm also implementing cloudflare.

I didnt see this question asked so I thought it might make an interesting question. From my domain carrier I am pointing the nameservers to Cloudflare but in Cloudflare for me to get this to work do I just need to create the CNAME to point to the subdomain? I cannot direct the IP because the IP is always dynamic for Heroku.

How would this be setup?

Comment: Are you wanting to use a CDN in front of your chat subdomain?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two things.

1. You need to point the subdomain to Heroku using a `CNAME`.  You do that by editing your DNS records.   Since you are using CloudFlare as your DNS host, you need to add a `CNAME` through their interfaces.  They have [instructions for doing so here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019093151-Managing-DNS-records-in-Cloudflare).
2. Add the subdomain host name to your Heroku account (or wherever you eventually choose to host the chat room).  When Heroku gets requests for this sub-domain, they need to know that they should be serving your content.

Answer (score -2):

I would first set up the hosting and cnames with heroku. Then I will proceed to implement cloudflare.

Comment: Welcome to Pro Webmasters. We prefer reasonably [detailed answers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) here. Can you elaborate on the steps you suggest taking in more detail? Thanks.